# Why am I getting an error in my main.xml?

Tags: android

See image here :

[image]

I get error in `setContentView(R.layout.main);` Where is my problem?

Comment: Well, have you looked at line 17 of Convert.java?

Comment: There is an error in your layout xml. Please post main.xml and we will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have invalid value set for layout_width (="match_parent"). "fill_parent" is maybe what you're looking for. "match_parent" is available only for API level 8 and higher.